# My token seems to be corrupted while getting saved in mysql table. Error: Authentication Failed: Could not obtain user details from token

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I am setting up my oauth2.0 authorization server using spring and persisting everything in db. While the token is generating but it seems to be corrupted while I see in the db. Hence the error Authentication failed Could not obtain user details from token. I am newbie at this and dont understand where I went wrong.

My AuthorizationServerConfigFile

```
package com.techprimers.security.springsecurityauthserver.config;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.ApprovalStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.JdbcApprovalStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dataSource")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder oauthClientPasswordEncoder;


    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {

        security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()")
                .passwordEncoder(oauthClientPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler oauthAccessDeniedHandler() {
        return new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApprovalStore approvalStore() {
        return new JdbcApprovalStore(dataSource);
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore()).authenticationManager(authenticationManager).userDetailsService(userDetailsService).approvalStore(approvalStore());
    }
}

My ResourceServerConfigFile

package com.techprimers.security.springsecurityauthserver.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;

@EnableResourceServer
@Configuration
public class ResourceServerConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .permitAll()
                ;
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
    }
}
```

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.techprimers.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-auth-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>spring-security-auth-server</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Dalston.SR3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

My SQL Table Schema

```
create table oauth_client_details (
  client_id VARCHAR(256) PRIMARY KEY,
  resource_ids VARCHAR(256),
  client_secret VARCHAR(256),
  scope VARCHAR(256),
  authorized_grant_types VARCHAR(256),
  web_server_redirect_uri VARCHAR(256),
  authorities VARCHAR(256),
  access_token_validity INTEGER,
  refresh_token_validity INTEGER,
  additional_information VARCHAR(4096),
  autoapprove VARCHAR(256)
);

create table test.oauth_client_token (
  token_id VARCHAR(256),
  token blob,
  authentication_id VARCHAR(256) PRIMARY KEY,
  user_name VARCHAR(256),
  client_id VARCHAR(256)
);

create table test.oauth_access_token (
  token_id VARCHAR(256),
  token blob,
  authentication_id VARCHAR(256) PRIMARY KEY,
  user_name VARCHAR(256),
  client_id VARCHAR(256),
  authentication blob,
  refresh_token VARCHAR(256)
);

create table test.oauth_refresh_token (
  token_id VARCHAR(256),
  token VARCHAR(256),
  authentication blob
);


create table test.oauth_approvals (
    userId VARCHAR(256),
    clientId VARCHAR(256),
    scope VARCHAR(256),
    status VARCHAR(10),
    expiresAt TIMESTAMP,
    lastModifiedAt TIMESTAMP
);
```

Token stored in db as blob when I try to open it in notepad this is the content

> ¬í sr Corg.springframework.security.oauth2.common.DefaultOAuth2AccessToken²ž6$úÎ L additionalInformationt Ljava/util/Map;L 
>   expirationt Ljava/util/Date;L refreshTokent ?Lorg/springframework/security/oauth2/common/OAuth2RefreshToken;L scopet Ljava/util/Set;L   tokenTypet Ljava/lang/String;L valueq ~ xpsr java.util.Collections$EmptyMapY6…ZÜçÐ  xpsr java.util.DatehjKYt  xpw  gÆ(‰–xsr Lorg.springframework.security.oauth2.common.DefaultExpiringOAuth2RefreshToken/ßGcÐÉ· L 
>   expirationq ~ xr Dorg.springframework.security.oauth2.common.DefaultOAuth2RefreshTokensá
>   cTÔ^ L valueq ~ xpt $b354edcc-f997-4f39-9b94-767e42af4c43sq ~   w  h`†xsr %java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet€’Ñ›€U  xr ,java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollectionB €Ë^÷ L ct Ljava/util/Collection;xpsr java.util.LinkedHashSetØl×Z•Ý*  xr java.util.HashSetºD…•–¸·4  xpw   ?@     t readt writext bearert $26c61cfc-8187-49e2-8fc4-6be199d935fd